# The type name 'UserDetailsDataRow' doesn't exist in the type 'UserDetails'

Tags: c#, datarow, datatableadapters

I am new to C# and currently using VS2010. When I try to do this:

```
UserDetailsTableAdapters.UserDetailsTableAdapter userDetails = new UserDetailsTableAdapters.UserDetailsTableAdapter();
UserDetails.UserDetailsDataTable loginDetailsTable = userDetails.GetData();
UserDetails.UserDetailsDataRow dataRow = null;
```

I get this error

> "The type name 'UserDetailsDataRow' doesn't exist in the type
>   'UserDetails'"

I have included the `using System.Data;` Any ideas what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it ?

Edit: UserDetails is a data set. I have a Table Adapter to an Access Database file. What I am trying to accomplish is to go through the set of existing users and at a later stage compare one of the values to check if it already exists. My idea was to get the row and compare one of the columns with a local variable for matches.

Comment: Can you explain more what is `UserDetails` what is the thing you are thing to accomplish here

Comment: @Phantomazi Why do you think that `UserDetails` type contains `UserDetailsDataRow` type? Or that it has something to do with `System.Data` namespace? Both those types are your user defined types(there are no such types in the framework, at least as I know), so the problem is that your code(or some third-party code you use) doesn't contain `UserDetails` with nested `UserDetailsDataRow` type.

Comment: @EugenePodskal I thought so because I am following a tutorial and there this worked. Sorry, as I said I am a beginner taking my first steps

Comment: Then you probably forgot to add definition of `UserDetailsDataRow` to your `UserDetails` class. Try to recheck the tutorial once more.

Comment: what makes you think that this data set contains this property `UserDetailsDataRow` i think you need to rethink the technique of your work